# Element`s absolute positioning issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to include the `children elements size whose position is absolute` into there `parents size`, i means to say :

We have :

**MarkUP**

```
        <div class="parent">
         <div class="children">
           My position is absolute.
         </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
         .parent      // position by default static
          {
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
          }

          .children
          {
            position :absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
          }
```

My problem is the height of parent is 0, may be because of its children absolute positioning. So is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden` to the `.parent` element?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when you are using percentage values for setting height of an element, the height if `html` and `body` should be 100% as well.

Comment: In my case i am adding element dynamically in my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use JavaScript? Inman's position clearing method will do the job for you:

http://shauninman.com/assets/examples/si-clear-children-1.0/si-clear-children-1.0.zip

More info here:
http://shauninman.com/archive/2006/05/22/clearance_position_inline_absolute

Answer (score 0):

Old post but someone might find this useful. if you are willing to use javascript

http://shinytoyrobots.com/2011/11/super-simple-jquery-height-manipulation/